# Comprehension issue with the delete[] operator used on c++ arrays

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

Hello I know that in C if I do the following I will get a memory leak:

```
int *b = malloc(128*sizeof(int));
b = b+25;
free(b);
```

Now I was trying to understand if the new[] and the delete[] operators have the same problem or not.
Would I get a memory leak if I write the following ?

```
int* bcpp = new int[128];
bcpp +=25;
delete[] bcpp;
```

Comment: What you "know that" is in fact not true at all. Your first code snippet, just as your second, have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun You can't really test code that exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza Using valgrind or some other tool won't tell that?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Doesn't matter what it tells you since it might change when Moon and Jupiter line up...

Comment: I would say behavior is the same. I think difference with c++ new is that you can use a try catch and get a OutOfMemory exception when you are ... out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### 7.22.3.3 The `free` function
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> 2 The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a *null pointer*, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined**.
>   3 The `free` function returns no value.

Passing a pointer to `delete []` which does not come from `new []` in C++ has the same adverse effect as passing a pointer to `free` which does not come from a corresponding allocation function in C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

`free` or `delete[]` must be invoked on pointers returned by `malloc` or `new[]` or on a `nullptr`. If invoked on anything else, your program has *undefined behavior*.

This means that in **both your examples**, you could get a leak or a free pizza or whatever, everything is legal.

An example for a leak in C++ would be the following:

```
void fun () {
    int* p = new int[128];
}
```

Now you have no way to delete `p`, so the memory pointed to by `p` is leaked.